# Counting the sum of prime number

Tags: c++, sum

I am trying to count the sum of how many times I found the prime number b/w 1-100.

So say I am running the iteration 100 times and between those iterations whenever I find a prime number, I go ahead and print it. But how do I add that how many total prime numbers have I found?

Any help would be appreciated.

```
bool isPrimeNumber(int number){

    bool isPrimeFlag;
        
    for(int i =2; i<number; i++){

            //bcze its divisible and gets you 0 as a remainder
            //we set the flag as false
        if(number % i==0){
            //isPrimeFlag = false;
            //break;
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}


int main(){

    int result = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i<=100; i++){

        bool isPrime = isPrimeNumber(i);
        //counting until 100
        // cout << i <<endl;
        if(isPrime){
    
                cout << i << " is prime number\n"; 
        }
    }
    //cout << "Their are "<< result << "Prime Numbers b/w 1-100";
}
```

Comment: right after you print your prime number, increment your result(so it should be done in if statement)

Comment: is this for project euler? heard of the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can keep a counter and increment in the loop if it is prime, like this.

```
bool isPrimeNumber(int number){

    bool isPrimeFlag;
        
    for(int i =2; i<number; i++){

            //bcze its divisible and gets you 0 as a remainder
            //we set the flag as false
        if(number % i==0){
            //isPrimeFlag = false;
            //break;
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}


int main(){

    int result = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i<=100; i++){

        bool isPrime = isPrimeNumber(i);
        //counting until 100
        // cout << i <<endl;
        if(isPrime){
    
                cout << i << " is prime number\n"; 
                result++;
        }
    }
    cout << "There are "<< result << "Prime Numbers b/w 1-100";
}
```

Comment: ghad, I'm so dumb. Thank you. I could think in my mind about how to count. But I couldn't put it into the code. Appreciate it man.